# How can I cherry-pick from "Android Studio branch" to "Eclipse branch"

Tags: android, git, git-cherry-pick

Right now I'm working on a fork of a project and I need to cherry-pick some changes from the master branch to the forked branch.

The problem is that master is updated to the new project structure.

So source files are located in `./src/main/java` instead of `./src`

Any suggestion how to cherry-pick changes from master?

Answer (score 1):

For GIT it shouldn't be a problem, cause GIT track file changes throughout the project. If you are working on the same repository but on other branches you can use rebase. [Here](http://mettadore.com/analysis/a-simple-git-rebase-workflow-explained/) is a nice example.

Otherwise I think the good way is to create git path for specific commit in master project and apply it to fork project. [Here](http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) you can see that it is not difficult

To avoid issues related to different IDEs I recommend do that via console. 
In both cases, it might be a need to resolve the conflicts, good luck!

Comment: Rebase is not an option in this case, will try 2nd option tomorrow! :) thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, I just figured out that I can simply modify patch before applying!